# Trouble sending info between view controllers with modal presentation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I am having trouble sending info from one viewcontroller to the next. In my storyboard I am using a modal presentation. When I write the destinationviewcontroller is when I get the error. If I do not write that line the code works ok. Any ideas?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueEditItem") {

        // if I erase the next 2 lines the code will run ok
        let ss = segue.destinationViewController as EditItemViewController
        ss.toPassID = toPassID

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out:

```
let ss = (segue.destinationViewController.visibleViewController as EditItemViewController)
```

I think you already set in your Storyboard Settings or your segue the presentation to "Modal" ?